# TripIt long last token

Tags: objective-c, ios, oauth

When I login to tripit in my app I get an access token. How can I an access token so that I could access protected resources any other time I use my app? Without getting the request token again and without authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [TripIt API documentation](http://tripit.github.com/api/doc/v1/index.html), especially the OAuth section. You exchange the Request Token for an Access Token. The Access Token is stored on your side for the user and is used to access protected resources going forward. Once you have an Access Token, you don't need to be authorized again or deal with a Request Token again.

Comment: I just don't understand what I am missing. I save access token and token secret, pass  it to oauth object but when I try to get protected resources, I get error 'error=Authentication needed, status=401, response=(null)'

Comment: Can you post your code? It will make figuring out what's wrong easier.

Comment: Ok, this is main oauth Oauth.m file http://pastebin.com/atyj0DgZ
I am using this library https://github.com/j4n0/oauth
And in my ViewController.m http://pastebin.com/HZ8A7uxd
requestTemporaryCredentials in this library is getting request token,
requestOwnerAuthorization is authorization and requestTokenCredentials is getting access token. I commented the last one when I tried to get protected resourses without authorization.

Comment: Huh, Thanks for pointing to the documentation:) The description of error 401 made me to check oauth token and secret that I pass:) I just stored oauth token for oauth token secret:) But the other question is, how long does this token last, I didnt really find any description of it. Does it mean that it is given for eternity or until the user changes his password?)

Comment: The TripIt Access Tokens are setup to last for eternity. It's not tied to the user's password, so you don't know or care if they change their password. The only way you could be affected is if the user goes into TripIt and explicitly revokes your token.

Comment: @ Alexander....i trying to same as u provided code but i got the error that 401 consumer key is not present in the request